# jquery event only if condition met

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, eventtrigger

This is my script:

```
<script>

if( $('.mydiv').css('display') == 'block'){
    $(".input_a").keyup(function(){
        $(".input_b").val( this.value );
    }); 
};

$('.mybutton').toggle(
    function(){
        $('.mydiv').css('display','none');
        $(".input_b").val('');
        // now, the event inside the "IF" here above should not occur but it does...
    },
    function(){
        $('.mydiv').css('display','block');
        var f1 = $(".input_a").val();
        $(".input_b").val(f1);
    }        
);

</script>
```

What I'm tring to do:

I have to input fields and a div displayed.

- If the div is shown, I want the input B to be an exact copy of the input A (in real time)
- if the div is hidden, I want the input B to be cleared and ready to be filled-in.
- This is where I have a problem: if the div is hidden, typing something in the input A should NOT be mirrored on the input B.

This is what my script is about, but the "IF" doesn't seem to work as when the div is hidden, filling in the input B is still mirrored on the input B.

Where am I wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **[:visible-selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** like,

```
if( $('.mydiv:visible').length){
    $(".input_a").keyup(function(){
        $(".input_b").val( this.value );
    }); 
};
```

Or you can use **[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** like

```
if( $('.mydiv').is(':visible')){
   ...
}
```

Use `$('.mydiv').hide();` in place of `$('.mydiv').css('display','none');`

And use `$('.mydiv').show();` in place of `$('.mydiv').css('display','block');`

Read [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) and [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show)

Try the **Full code**

```
$(function(){
    if( $('.mydiv').is(':visible')) {// use is and :visible selector
        $(".input_a").keyup(function(){
            $(".input_b").val( this.value );
        }); 
    };

    $('.mybutton').toggle(function(){
            $('.mydiv').hide(); // use hide()
            $(".input_a").off('keyup');// off/remove the keyup event
            $(".input_b").val('');
        }, function(){
            $('.mydiv').show();// use show()
            var f1 = $(".input_a").val();
            $(".input_b").val(f1);
        }        
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very simple:

```
<script>
    $(".input_a").keyup(function(){
        if($('.mydiv').is(':visible')){
            $(".input_b").val($(this).val());
        }else {
            $(".input_b").val('');
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: It probably doesn't fit my needs as it is simpler with one pair of inputs, indeed, but it becomes more complicated (too many conditions that are the same) when you have a whole form to process this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `.is(':visible')`

```
if( $('.mydiv').is(':visible')){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //cache variables
    var $ina = $(".input_a"),
        $inb = $(".input_b"),
        $div = $('.mydiv');
    $ina.keyup(function () {
        //check the condition within the keyup handler
        if ($div.is(':visible')) {
            $inb.val(this.value);
        };
    });

    $('.mybutton').toggle(function () {
        $div.hide();
        $inb.val('');
    }, function () {
        $div.show();
        $inb.val($ina.val());
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QGfvw/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. "is visible" alone, wasn't enough